# Table columns widths not being respected

Tags: html, css, outlook

I'm having a bit of a problem putting together a HTML email which will render properly in outlook, i had initially got everything working fine through the use of list items and the list-style-image Property, but that isn't supported in outlook.

Basically, i have a table with 2 rows in it, the left hand side one has an 11pixel image being using as a custom bullet point, and on the right hand side is some text.

My problem is no matter what i do i cannot get the column on the left to maintain an 11 pixel width, the columns ALWAYS split equally down the middle of the table. Help please?

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="Small Image" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">
            <h4>
                TEXT
            </h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="webinar">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left">
                        <img src="/Bullet.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="right">
                        <p>
                            TEXT
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td.webinar .left {
    width:11px;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0px
    margin:0px
}

td.webinar .right {
    width:144px;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0px
    margin:0px
}

td.webinar {
    background-color:#ccc6d2;
    border:1px solid #313131;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you want to use css styles in emails? then you are going to have a bad time  in most clients..

try to:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="144px">
        <img src="Small Image" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in email templates you should always apply inline styling as "oldschool" as possible!

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work ._.
I've written tonnes of emails with CSS styling in them and they've all up to this point turned out fine, i have no idea why it's splitting it down the middle like this. It's the Class="Webinar" section that is the problem

Comment: It renders perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE, so yes, just in Outlook, but i don't see why something as simple as having 2 columns with different widths is refusing to work